# Evil mode - How to go into Insert mode after Org-capture with %? cursor placement

Tags: evil, org-capture

After creating an org-capture with the %? to place the cursor, the cursor will be in command mode. Is there a variable for putting it into insert mode or does org-capture elisp code need to be directly editted?

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("e" "Example" entry (file+headline "~/org/notes.org" "Example")
         "* TODO  %?\n  %u\n")))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Credits to awalker4 from reddit!

```
(add-hook 'org-capture-mode-hook 'evil-insert-state)
```